# How to retrieve git changes

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have cloned  repository to new folder. In the new folder I have made some changes after making changes i created one more branch to load the new folder.

[image] from git cmd I have used

a) `git status`

b) `git add .`

c) `git commit`

d) `git push origin branchname`

e) `git fetch && git checkout`

Now in the new folder I cant able to see the changes all the new changes has been removed and it is updated with the initial clone code .
How can I retrieve the changes made earlier

Comment: Without knowing I used git fetch && git checkout branchname so everything in branchname has been replaced with master code How to cancel that retrieve

Comment: Could you explain in more detail please? You did 1. Clone repo 2. Made changes 3. Create new branch 4. Applied changes with the commands you wrote and then you loose which data?

Comment: I have commited and pushed into new branch but after i have used git fetch && git checkout newbranch. When i checkout all the changes are vanished and code exists in master branch is same as code in new branch

Comment: Does your changes stays in the `origin branchname` that you pushed?